# passing value from service to component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I am having a real problem passing a variable from a service (LibraryService) down to a component which is one level deeper in the directory structure (ReadingPaneComponent). This is after I won a pitched battle getting this variable into the service from a component which is TWO levels deeper (AuthorsComponent). Effectively, the ReadingPaneComponent is therefore an "aunt/uncle" to the AuthorsComponent, hence my trying to send the variable via the existing LibraryService, which also serves to draw down data from my backend database.

All I am trying to do is pass a number of up to five digits which represents the ID of a book into the ReadingPaneComponent. The number is detected perfectly well by the service but I cannot for love nor money get it into the ReadingPaneComponent as anything other than 'undefined'. I am also calling a method defined in the ReadingPaneComponent from the AuthorsComponent when the user clicks on a book title, so this may be an issue with asynchronous calls or what lifecycle hook the method in the ReadingPaneComponent should sit in (current ngOnInit but I recognise this is probably wrong, and have tried alternatives to no avail).

This is the relevant code from **library.service.ts**: -

```
import { Injectable, Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Language } from '../shared/language.model';
import { Author } from '../shared/author.model';
import { Book } from '../shared/book.model';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';
import {
  AngularFireDatabase,
  AngularFireList,
  AngularFireObject } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';

@Injectable()
export class LibraryService {
  private chosenBookSource = new Subject<number>();
  chosenBook$ = this.chosenBookSource.asObservable();

// MORE CODE HERE

chosenBook(data) {
    console.log(data); //This shows the correct ID of the book clicked by the user, so I know this is working properly.
    this.chosenBookSource.next(data);
    return data;
  }
```

This is from **reading-pane.component.ts**: -

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { LibraryService } from '../library.service';
import { Language } from '../../shared/language.model';
import { Author } from '../../shared/author.model';
import { Book } from '../../shared/book.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-reading-pane',
  templateUrl: './reading-pane.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./reading-pane.component.css'],
  providers: [LibraryService]
})
export class ReadingPaneComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() bookPGID: number;
  public bookHTML;

  constructor(private libraryService: LibraryService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.libraryService.chosenBook$);
    this.libraryService.chosenBook$.subscribe(data => (this.bookPGID = data));
    console.log(this.bookPGID);
    this.libraryService
      .loadBook(this.bookPGID)
      .subscribe((book: Observable<any>) => (this.bookHTML = book));
  }
```

The call in the AuthorsComponent works because it does trigger the `loadBook` function in the ReadingPaneComponent, it's just that the ID number does not survive the journey from the LibraryService into the ReadingPaneComponent.

Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: Where is `chosenBook` (the method from your service, without `$` at the end) called?

Comment: I tried exchanging the  this.libraryService.chosenBook$.subscribe(data => (this.bookPGID = data)); for  this.libraryService.chosenBook(data).subscribe(data => (this.bookPGID = data)); but the component threw an error over the (data) argument saying it didn't exist. To be honest I've worked on several different suggestions from elsewhere on SO to the point where I've become utterly confused as to what arguments to declare. I might have another go at this by declaring an argument in the component.

Comment: I've actually called chosenBook (without the $) in the Authors Component: this was the only way as I recall that I could get the ID variable into the Service two folder levels above it. The console log now records the correct ID of the book title clicked on but the function in the Reading Pane Component is still unable to pick up that variable.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is where LibraryService is being declared.

If `ReadingPaneComponent` is used inside of `AuthorsComponent`, like:

```html
<!-- AuthorsComponent.html -->
<h1>Authors</h1>
...
<reading-pane-component></reading-pane-component>
```

Then try removing `providers: [LibraryService]` from reading pane's `@component` decorator. That declaration is creating a new instance of LibraryService for each instance of your reading pane component. If you remove that declaration from reading pane, it will inherit the LibraryService from its parent instead, i.e. the authors component.

If your reading pane is not being used inside of authors, then try declaring the LibraryService provider in your app module instead. Remove `providers: [LibraryService]` from both authors and reading pane components. Then add it to your app's `@NgModule` decorator.

[Have a look at this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/w4PKDgi6HsTk4CfDhHt0?p=preview), you'll see:

1. LibraryServiceOnce declared in `src/app.ts`. The value this produces is the same through out the app
2. LibraryService declared in `src/AuthorsComponent.ts`. It produces a different value for each instance of an author component
3. A read pane component nested inside authors with no LibraryService providers declared. It takes its value from its parent author component instead.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, I picked this tip up elsewhere, and the service is now provided only in the App Module, but it made no difference. I've even tried wrapping everything that I want the Reading Pane to do in ngDoCheck just to make sure those functions are being fired but the variable in console.log(this.bookPGID); is still coming up undefined.

Comment: It turns out that I'd got an extraneous provision of the service in the parent component of the Authors Component. I've removed this now and the variable passes across. Many thanks!

Comment: No probs, glad you found the culprit!